# APScheduler Get next_run_time

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am looking to get the [next_run_time](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/job.html#apscheduler.job.Job) of a scheduled job but I receive an `AttributeError` when on that. How do I properly access it:

```
sched.add_job(myFunc, 'cron', minute='*', start_date=datetime(2023,1,1), end_date=datetime(2023,1,3))
for job in sched.get_jobs():
    print(job.next_run_time)
sched.start()
```

Am I accessing this variable wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call sched.start() first before job.next_run_time